# how to enable the default internet upstream of wwan and wan in my gateway without adding any specific commands

Tags: linux, networking, iproute

I am using intel gateway so in my case the default internet upstream was enabled for wan port but i am using both wan and 3g-wwan.so i want to enable the default internet connectivity for both wan and 3g-wwan ports.

In case of wan port disconnect the 3g-wwan port automatically enabled the internet connectivity

I tried this command "**ip route add default via x.x.x.x dev 3g-wwan**" it is also gives some conflictions.

please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your conflict is that you are trying to add two default routes. Try adding priority (metric):

```
ip route add default via x.x.x.x dev 3g-wwan metric 1
```